# Show that the function is differentiable in $0$ and that the derivative is also continuous: $g(x)=\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sin x}, g(0):= 0$

Tags: real-analysis

(I already know that $g$ is continuous at $0$)

In this case $g$ is defined on the interval $[0,\pi/2]$

According to the Riemann lemma if there is a function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable such that the derivative is also continuous then for $F(k):=\int_a^bf(x)\sin kx dx$ we have $\lim_{|k|\rightarrow \infty}F(k)=0$.

I want to use this to show $\lim_{\lambda\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\lambda x)g(x)dx=0$

In order to do so I have to show that the function is differentiable in $0$ and that the derivative is also continuous there.

I hope somebody can give me some hints to solve this problem.

Comment: If you're allowed to use complex analysis, this is easy.  $\frac{1}{\sin z}$ has a simple pole of residue $1$ at the origin, so the given function is entire.

Answer (score 0):

To prove differentiability at zero, you can use the following consequence of the Mean Value Theorem.

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function and differentiable on $(a,b)$. If there exists $\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f'(x)$ (finite or improper) then there exists $f'^+(a)$ and it holds  $f'^+(a)=\lim\limits_{x\to a^+}f'(x)$. Here $f'^+(a)$ denotes the derivative of $f$ at point $a$ from the right side.

Analogous statement is true for the derivative from left.

So if you are able to check the assumptions of this statement the continuous differentiability at point $a$ follows.